# Setting to open all OneNote windows in "normal view"?

Tags: windows, microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to have all OneNote windows open in a particular view mode?

For example, I would like to be able to have each window open in Normal View.

Comment: Kindly check if this article was helpful: [Personalizing the OneNote Interface](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2232119&seqNum=6#:~:text=To%20toggle%20back%20to%20Normal,bar%20and%20page%20tabs%20bar.)

Answer (score 0):

Each tab is separate and maintains its own settings. There is not a global setting to have all pages set to normal view.

In my own One Note 365 experience over the years and in all the articles I looked at, there is no single setting to achieve what you would like. It is all set by One Note page.

[One Note Views](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/microsoft-onenote-2013/9780735672758/changing_screen_views.html)

> OneNote 2013 offers three views in which you can choose to work. In
> Full Page view, the Notebooks pane and page tabs do not appear. In
> Normal view, you can see the Notebooks pane and page tabs. Normal view
> is the best view for writing, editing, and organizing notes; Full Page
> view is best for reading notes comfortably.

[One Note Normal view](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_win10-mso_o365b/any-way-to-change-to-layout-view-of-onenote-for/85cb1334-7624-40c0-8f06-fb8e79f28943?auth=1)

> In OneNote windows 10 according to this article Get started with the
> new OneNote the new layout is by design and I'm afraid currently,
> there is no setting to change a layout of OneNote windows 10.
>
> Given the situation, we welcome and encourage you to share your ideas
> through User Voice. It is the best way to perfect our products and
> services. Many features have been developed or upgraded directly from
> your ideas. OneNote for Windows UserVocie.